# How to add extral level with outlines package?

Tags: packages, itemize

How can I add a 5th level of depth with the `outlines` Package?

```
\setlistdepth{5}
```

does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
%\setlistdepth{5}
\begin{document}
\section{start}
\begin{outline}
\1 foo
\2 bar
\3 too
\4 foo
%\5 bar
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

-

This is the solution to expand Outlines Package in depth

-> [tex.stackexchange.com/a/262835/124842](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262835/124842)

Comment: The `outlines` package has no command `\setlistdepth` and the manual clearly states right at the beginning, title page(!!!), that there are at most 4 levels. Is you need more (!!!!) than 4 levels (why?), you have either hack into `outlines` code or switch to `enumitem` which allows for more levels, but you have to drop the syntax of `outlines` then (and have to provide the labelling in `\setlist` definitions of your own

Comment: Related and maybe helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262835/124842

Comment: @novski: There's no need to add `SOLVED` to the title... Now the question bumps up and enters the Reopen - Review Queue :-(

Comment: ok. please excuse...